# How to use # in linux terminal command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, terminal

One of the character in my password contains # symbol. Due this, the shell omit rest of the command after # symbol. For example I have executed the following command in terminal,

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u "https://admin:#D******9@ca.m-zzz.n-zzzz.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002" --tls.certfiles /home/ec2-user/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem -M /home/ec2-user/admin-msp
```

Due to # symbol in the password, I am getting the following error,

```
Error: Failed to create default configuration file: No username and password provided as part of the Fabric CA server URL
```

Comment: Try '\' as this is the character escape operator in strings

Comment: Already tried. But no luck.

Comment: Try wrapping the string in a (`'`) instead of a double-quote (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes(') instead of double quotes(") if you need to use special characters in CLI

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u 'https://admin:#D******9@ca.m-zzz.n-zzzz.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002' --tls.certfiles /home/ec2-user/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem -M /home/ec2-user/admin-msp
```